# how to serve .swf flash files with static links using rails - asset pipeline or not? using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, flash, asset-pipeline

Scenario

The rails application is running mongoid. For every instance in the below model, there's a portfolio field which needs to be a .swf flash file.

```
 class Person
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :name, type: String
    field :skill, type: String
    field :portfolio, type: String # portfolio will be a flash .swf and needs to have a static live url on the server
 end
```

How do I arrange the the model to save the file locally on the server so every file will have a unique URL. ( not using carrierwave or paperclip )

Should I use asset pipeline or not? Because I'll be saving these files locally.

The end result I'm looking for is something like this:

http://www.persons.com/persons/portfolios/some_unique_id

A person can have only one portfolio, thus, not using reference.